# How to install a lex tool in Manjaro Linux?

Tags: lex, archlinux, manjaro, pacman-package-manager

I tried installing bison and flex :

```
sudo pacman -Syu install bison flex
```

This is what I got:

```
:: Synchronizing package databases...
core is up to date
extra is up to date
community is up to date
multilib is up to date
error: target not found: install
warning: flex-2.6.4-2 is up to date -- reinstalling
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sudo pacman -Syu install bison flex
> ```

There is not a package nor a sub-command named "install".  To install/upgrade
packages, `pacman -Syu` is usually enough:

```
sudo pacman -Syu bison flex
```

From the "EXAMPLES" section in the [pacman(8)](https://www.archlinux.org/pacman/pacman.8.html) man page:

> pacman -Syu gpm
>
> Update package list, upgrade all packages, and then install gpm if it wasn’t already installed.

See also [Pacman#Installing_packages](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pacman#Installing_packages).